# Is it possible to animate filter in Fabric.js?

Tags: fabricjs

Is it possible to animate the images filter in Fabric.js? Such as a "pixelate" filter.

Comment: How exactly do you want to animate the filter? Which parameter should be changing in a period of time?

Comment: eg Filter brightness to slowly change the brightness

Comment: and where you can ask questions in Russian

Comment: If you drag brightness slider in this demo — http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/ — I think that's the effect you want. That's the property you need to animate (via, for example, `fabric.util.animate` http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.util.html#.animate)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in the same way like the demo.
Unfortunately filters aren't able to be animated - they need too much processing time.

Here's my Code:

```
image = ... //Image, where the filter should be applied

var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite({
    threshold: 0,
    distance:  140
});
image.filters.push(filter);
image.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

animate(image,1, 400);   //Start the Animation

function animate(image,value, stop){
    value += ((stop-value)*0.02);    //Change the threshold-value

    if (image.filters[0]) {   
        image.filters[0]['threshold'] = value;
        console.log(value);
        image.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));  //Start creating the new image

        if(value<stop-100){
            setTimeout(function(){act(image,value,stop);},1);  
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code isn't the most efficient one, but it works. And you can see that Animating filters consumes too much time.

(I tested it with a 1920x1080px image, maybe you can use it with smaller images)

Comment: Using `fabric.util.requestAnimFrame` would probably be more efficient (instead of manual recursive `setTimeout`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a updated version for the brightness filter

```
  var brightnessValue = 0.9;
  var brightnessFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({
    brightness: brightnessValue
  });
  fabricImage.filters.push(brightnessFilter);

  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function brightnessFilterAnimation() {
    brightnessValue = brightnessValue - 0.04;
    brightnessFilter.brightness = brightnessValue;
    fabricImage.applyFilters();
    if (brightnessValue > 0) {
      fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(brightnessFilterAnimation);
    }
  });
```